# iOS: recommended solution configurations to create IPA file

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to create **IPA** file to publish on *App Store* but i confuse which mode is better to generate IPA file whether **Debug** or **Release**. I have publish my app last 2 times using both mode debug and release individually, However it is accepting both IPA files.
What is the recommended mode to generate IPA file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way in which I release to the app store is to archive my project first by setting the device to `Build only device - Generic iOS Device` and then **Product > Archive**.

Note: Make sure you set the correct build version etc...

Once it has finished archiving, open up Organizer - **Window > Organizer**
Find your archive and click **Export > App Store** and then follow the instructions. Once it has finished exporting, choose a destination and it will have exported your app into an IPA into your chosen location.

Once you have done this click **Xcode > Open Developer Tool > Application Loader** and click Choose, select your IPA and then follow the instructions, it will then begin to upload to iTune Connect where you can then release to the app store

Comment: I  agree with you but in starting itself you haven't mention the mode what you are selecting like debug or release specially when you want to release the app

Comment: If it is going to the app store is it always Release you select.

Comment: thank you @Niall,  As i mention both IPA files app store accepting, than what is the difference between those _modes_  in production or after releasing

Comment: The main difference is that the code isn't optimised for the app store when in debug. It also contains the complete symbolic information that is used when debugging. The release version is a lot smaller and more "App store ready".